# How to include html elements inside a webcontrol such as a TableCell in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am writing a code in webforms to add rows to a table after a button click. and inside some cells i need add html elements like textbox and dropdows,

```
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();    
        cell1.Text = "<input type=\"text\"></input>";
        row.Cells.Add(cell1);
        //proptable is the table id
        PropTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

it works if i write like this. 
but is there a more accurate way to do this?
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add Controls to TextBox easily like this:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
        textbox.Text = "Testing...";
        //cell1.Text = "<input type=\"text\"></input>";
        cell1.Controls.Add(textbox);
        row.Cells.Add(cell1);
        //proptable is the table id
        PropTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```